# Excel Index and Match Function to verify data

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I have 2 spreadsheets of user data from 2 different systems.
I want to use a combination of conditions. I want to look for matches that contain 2 of the 3 conditions but it must include the C2 condition regardless.
So Ideally something like ...Match(A2&C2 OR B2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&'Old System'!B:B&'Old System'!I:I,0)),"")

This is the formula I am currently using but I have noticed it looks for matches of all 3 conditions rather than what I'm looking for.

**=IFERROR(INDEX('Old System'!K:K,MATCH(A2&B2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&'Old System'!B:B&'Old System'!I:I,0)),"")**

Just for context, here are the matching columns between the two systems

Old System K - $ amount paying in old system, New System A -> Old System A - User ID, New System B -> Old System B - Name, New System C -> Old System I - Payment Group Name

Answer (score 0):

I would match the first and third column and then if that errored out match the second and third.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Old System'!K:K,IFERROR(MATCH(A2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&'Old System'!B:B,0),
                                  MATCH(B2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&'Old System'!B:B,0))),"")
```

You could also do this with an XLOOKUP if your version of Excel supports it.

```
XLOOKUP(A2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!K:K,
       XLOOKUP(B2&C2,'Old System'!A:A&'Old System'!B:B,'Old System'!K:K,""))
```